# Prevent navbar-right text from wrapping in navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In [this Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/133310), how do I prevent the `navbar-right` text from wrapping in the mobile view? I want all the text to stay on one line, getting progressively closer as the width of the page shrinks, viz. a compressed version of what is seen in the desktop view. At any given width, the margins on either side should be what Bootstrap would normally do at that width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since navbar-right is impacted by the Bootstrap CSS at smaller screen widths, you can alternately use `pull-left` and `pull-right`..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Left Text</p>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Right Text</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```